# images API / Error

Tags: python, google-app-engine, api, image

I'm working on a project and I used the the Images Python API .
For instance in the example given in   http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/images/usingimages.html
I get an error when ever I do not upload a photo, How can I modify the code so I don't get an error when I don't post anything.

thanks

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the line

```
avatar = images.resize(self.request.get("img"), 32, 32)
```

to check if `self.request.get("img")` is empty:

```
posted_avatar = self.request.get("img")
if posted_avatar:
  avatar = images.resize(posted_avatar, 32, 32)
  greeting.avatar = db.Blob(avatar)

greeting.put()
```

Comment: @Adam Bernier, your sample got me thinking whether `put()` should be moved out of `if`...

Answer (score 1):

You can simply check if that input element of the form was populated.

From the example code:

```
<div><input type="file" name="img" /></div>
```

You'd then add a conditional (`if` statement) to your handler:

```
if self.request.get("img"):
    # do image processing stuff here
```

Here's a simple bit of code that does what you want:  http://bitbucket.org/abernier/pocasi/src/tip/handlers/admin.py#cl-102
Template code here:  http://bitbucket.org/abernier/pocasi/src/tip/templates/create.html